# Making RDD operations on sqlContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, rdd

I am working on a tutorial in apache spark, and I making use of the Cassandra database, Spark2.0, and Python

I am trying to do an RDD Operation on a sql Query, using this tutorial, 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/sql-programming-guide.html
it says #The results of SQL queries are RDDs and support all the normal RDD operations.

I currently have this line of codes that says

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT word FROM tweets where word like '%@%'").show(20, False)
    df = sqlContext.read\
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
    .options(table="wordcount", keyspace= "demo")\
    .load()
df.select("word")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("tweets")

usernames = results.map(lambda p: "User: " + p.word)
for name in usernames.collect():
    print(name)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'map'
If the variable results is a result of sql Query, why am I getting this error? Can anyone please explain this to me.

Everything works fine, the tables print, only time I get an error is when I
try to do a RDD Operation. 
please bear in mind sc is an existing spark context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `show()` only prints content.

Use:

```
results = sqlContext.sql("SELECT word FROM tweets where word like '%@%'")
result.show(20, False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I took out result.show and now I get a 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map' Error.

Comment: resultsDF = results.rdd.map(lambda p: "User: " + p.word) worked graciously. Thank you.